# OpenCL выдает неверный результат

Tags: c++, opencl

Пишу на opencl программу, которая должна складывать массивы поэлементно, но результат очень странный.

test.cl:

```
__kernel void test(__global int* a, __global int* b, __global int* c)
{
    int i = get_group_id(0);
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#ifdef MAC
#include <CL/OpenCL.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif


void runCL(int* a, int* b, int* c, size_t n) {
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context ctx;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_mem a_mem, b_mem, c_mem;
    cl_int err;

    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, 0);
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, &device, 0);
    ctx = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device, 0, 0, &err);
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, 0, &err);


    std::ifstream sourceFile(R"(D:\Projects\C++\FirstOpenCL\FirstOpenCL\test.cl)");
    std::stringstream bufferSource;
    bufferSource << sourceFile.rdbuf();
    std::string tempSource = bufferSource.str();
    const char* source = tempSource.data();

    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &source, 0, &err);
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "test", &err);


    size_t buffer_size = sizeof(int) * n;
    a_mem = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, buffer_size, 0, &err);
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, a_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, buffer_size, a, 0, 0, 0);
    b_mem = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, buffer_size, 0, &err);
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, b_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, buffer_size, b, 0, 0, 0);
    c_mem = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, buffer_size, 0, &err);
    err = clFinish(queue);

    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_mem);
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &b_mem);
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &c_mem);

    size_t global_work_size = n;
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, 0, &global_work_size, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    err = clFinish(queue);

    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, c_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, buffer_size, c, 0, 0, 0);
    err = clFinish(queue);

    clReleaseDevice(device);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(ctx);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseMemObject(a_mem);
    clReleaseMemObject(b_mem);
    clReleaseMemObject(c_mem);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
}

int main() {
    int n = 32;
    int* a = new int[n];
    int* b = new int[n];
    int* c = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = n - i;
    }



    runCL(a, b, c, n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " + " << b[i] << " = " << c[i] << "\n";
    }

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
}
```

результат программы:

```
0 + 32 = 32
1 + 31 = 0
2 + 30 = 0
3 + 29 = 0
4 + 28 = 0
5 + 27 = 0
6 + 26 = 0
7 + 25 = 0
8 + 24 = 0
9 + 23 = 0
10 + 22 = 0
11 + 21 = 0
12 + 20 = 0
13 + 19 = 0
14 + 18 = 0
15 + 17 = 0
16 + 16 = 0
17 + 15 = 0
18 + 14 = 0
19 + 13 = 0
20 + 12 = 0
21 + 11 = 0
22 + 10 = 0
23 + 9 = 0
24 + 8 = 0
25 + 7 = 0
26 + 6 = 0
27 + 5 = 0
28 + 4 = 0
29 + 3 = 0
30 + 2 = 0
31 + 1 = 0
```

Где проблема и как решить?

Comment: Сдается мне, что код выполняет одна группа `id` 0. Идентификатор группы - это как номер потока, а не индекс в исходном массиве.

Comment: @user7860670 , спасибо, изменил `get_group_id` на `get_global_i` и всё заработало)